What does it mean to have a law degree implicitly?
I read on https://iaals.du.edu/sites/default/files/documents/publications/judge_faq.pdf:

In every state, judges of the court of last resort, intermediate appellate court, and major trial court are required to have a law degree, either explicitly or implicitly.

What does it mean to have a law degree implicitly?

Regarding the comment:

I don't read the quote the way you read it. I read it as saying the requirement to have a law degree is explicit in some states and is implicit in other states. Does that change your question? Jen  Commented57 mins ago

If that is the case, I wonder how one can express an implicit requirement for a degree.

I would agree with @Jen's reading.  Some states have an explicit legal requirement that judges hold law degrees.  Other states have no legal requirement but have a very strong political preference that judges have law degrees such that it is implicitly required.  One could theoretically be appointed a judge in those states without having a law degree but appointing such a person would be a significant break with accepted norms that it is not done.  Thus, an implicit requirement.
Historically, becoming a lawyer by first attending law school is a practice that postdates many state constitutions.  It wouldn't have made sense to make law school an explicit requirement in the 18th century when most state constitutions were created because most lawyers were admitted to the bar after studying law under another lawyer.  And amending the state constitution to add that requirement is a lot of work if there is an unchallenged norm that enforces the requirement already.
There is technically no requirement that someone have a law degree in order to be appointed to the US Supreme Court.  The last justice to serve on the court without a law degree, James Byrnes, did so almost a century ago (1941-1942) and had passed the bar before then.  It makes sense to say that there is an implicit requirement to have a law degree in order to be appointed to the US Supreme Court because every person appointed in the last century has had that qualification (or had been admitted to the bar without attending law school) and there would be a significant uproar if a president nominated someone that didn't have a degree to the court.

a minor nit: 1941 is still less than a century ago

@littleadv - I shall pretend that I meant to say "almost a century" rather than looking at the digits of the year and thinking it was 2042...

@JustinCave considering that 2020 and 2021 felt like one year that took a decade to pass, you'd be not too wrong to think it was 2042...

There's a democracy/sovereignty issue too. If you say judges have to have a degree, today that means a school accredited by the ABA, a private organization. At least if you say judges have to have a law license, that's regulated by state bars, and those are overseen by some combination of the state Supreme Court, governor, legislator.

"appointing such a person would be a significant break with accepted norms that it is not done. "  I suggest that norms hold little sway over certain elements of recent political activites.
